# php json_decode for the contents of a .txt file

Tags: php, json, file, io

When I do the following,

```
    $res1 = '{"n":2,"stuff":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}';
    $res1 = json_decode($res);
    var_dump($res1);
```

It outputs:

```
object(stdClass)#289 (2) { ["n"]=> int(2) ["stuff"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#288 (2) { ["key1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["key2"]=> string(6) "value2" } } }
```

However, when I save the string $res1 into a .txt file named string.txt with the contents:

```
'{"n":2,"stuff":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}'
```

I do:

```
$filename = "path/string.txt";
$res2 = file_get_contents($filename);
$res2 = json_decode($res2);
```

It outputs:

```
NULL
```

How can I use json_decode for $res1 from a .txt file the same way as I can use json_decode for $res1 after declaration?

To Whom It May Concern:

A reason not mentioned about why it wasn't working for me was because my code editor didn't like the apostrophes (as in Name's) when declaring a $res1 with apostrophes, and I escaped the apostrophes as \' that became present in the string.txt file used for $res2.

Comment: I think your path is wrong. Are you absolutely sure it is correct?

Comment: Did you check that `file_get_contents($filename);` returns as expected?

Comment: Add to start of script to display all errors. ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Did you include the single quote marks around it in the file? That's a mistake

Comment: @Suboptimierer the path is just for the sake of example. Yes, it's correct. The file_get_contents($filename) returns string(54) "'{"n":2,"stuff":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}' " I changed the string.txt file so that file_get_contents returns "{"n":2,"stuff":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]} " and it still didn't work

Comment: @Adyson ok so, I removed the quote marks around it. I get string(52) "{"n":2,"stuff":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]} "  and for some reason there's a space at the end?

Comment: Wait, there was a newline at the end of the file. Now, file_get_contents returns string(51) "{"n":2,"stuff":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}"

Comment: OK, the issue was single quote marks around it. Now, it works! I swear I tried to correct that before and it didn't work. Maybe had a semicolon, a newline at the end, or something. Thank you all

Comment: No problem. Remember those outer single quotes were part of the PHP syntax for when you're declaring a literal string variable within the code. They aren't part of the JSON, so you don't need them when storing the raw data in a file (or database, or anything like that). Happy coding!